# How to create a child theme for LMS (with framework directory)

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

What is the right way to create a child theme for LMS theme (http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/lms/)? One of the problems with which I faced is that use own framework. And I don't know correct solution for this

[image]

As a solution is an override in child function.php path to the directory, but on an update, it can be an issue because new changes/functional will not be work as should.

Comment: You are the only one who knows what you mean by "LMS Theme".  Give us something to work with - a Google of "LMS Theme" turns up several results.

Comment: Why are you asking here about a theme you bought? Ask their support for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a framework along with a premium template?
Just use one or the other, and use the simple child theme generator at GPP if you don't know how to create a child theme:

https://graphpaperpress.com/wordpress-child-theme-generator/

Under parent theme select 'I don't see my theme here' and in the box that pops up just type in "lms" (without the quotation marks).

Upload the child theme zip you've created, activate it, and you're good to go. It's important to note that you'll possibly lose the changes you've already made to LMS using the customizer.

If I'm not understanding your question please explain why you require your own custom framework. I don't understand why you'd pay for a premium template, then couple it with your own framework. It's already built on a responsive framework...